# A solution for the WordPress source logs system

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

We are a site design team.
There is a problem in our work, when we carry out the project and deliver the client, the other programmers who work for that client are changing their project codes, that's why we plan to implement a system that creates a log in WordPress. You can create a log on the change code.
For example, there's a plugin that logs out what a person does in the WordPress panel, but there's nothing to be done when WordPress Codes change.
Have a service or solution for this issue ???

Comment: There is not really a solution if the person has access to the code. You could put the code with git and can see whatever has been changed since last pull. Also you could combine this with bash history or ftp logging etc. But if the person has the knowledge and want to avoid the logging with root access he can do this.

Comment: Im not sure what the question is, but I doubt its a good one for SO.  That said why does this `the other programmers who work for that client are changing their project codes` mean this `There is a problem in our work`  maybe its a translation thing, I am just not sure how you would be responsible for someone else messing something up...  You have no control over what their guys do and you shouldn't have to baby sit them...  Sure if you can come up with some workaround thats great, but don't look at it as your fault, that's my point .. lol